# Merging of DataTable Cells

Tags: c#, datatable

This may be a nonsensical question (as apparently all my last questions), but I wonder if there is a way to summarize adjacent cells of a DataTable.
Background:
I like to use DataTables as a source for DGVs to display tables to the user in a UI.This works great.
Now I have the problem that in a DGV I should preferably accommodate a legend as well. So much text also across some cell boundaries, preferably without changing the previous column width.
I wonder if this is possible or if I need to fill the DGV for this purpose again programmatically cell by cell?

Comment: Use datatable computer method : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the advise. But calculating values in a datatable is not my problem. Meanwhile I think solving my problem is not possible using a single datatable. I'll probably have to change the UI for this case.